# Почему реверсивный список возвращает None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я хочу занести реверсивный список в переменную, но ничего не выходит, он просто выводит None

```
a = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
reverse_a = a.reverse()
print(reverse_a)

None
```

Как это исправить?(python 3.8)

Comment: а вы распечатай a в конце :)

Comment: Можно просто использовать срез с обратной итерацией по всей длине `reverse_a = a[::-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `reverse` поворачивает сам список, но ничего не возвращает, используется так:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split(' '))) # 1 2 3 4 5
a.reverse()
print(a) # [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Если вы хотите занести новый список в переменную, не изменяя старого - используйте функцию `reversed()` (будьте внимательны, функция вернет итератор):

```
a = list(map(int, input().split(' '))) # 1 2 3 4 5 6
a_new = reversed(a)
print(list(a_new)) # [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Или самый, на мой взгляд, удобный способ - срез по всему списку с обратной итерацией:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split(' '))) # 1 2 3 4 5
a_new = a[::-1]
print(a_new) # [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```